# Do not show php files in the folder as the home directory

Tags: php, file, root

My files are in a folder named Project

link looks like this
http://sitename.com/project/news.php

How can I show you like home directory 
link looks like this (without deleting the project folder or not move)
http://sitename.com/news.php 
Source /project/news.php

Comment: By moving your files out of the directory

Comment: Do you have access to the apache conf file for your site?

Comment: yes I have access permission

Comment: Then just set the `DocumentRoot` and `Directory` paths appropriately.  Sounds you just have them set one level too high.

Answer (score 0):

If you have mod_rewrite enabled on your server and are using apache

make a file called .htaccess on the root

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on
   RewriteRule ^project(/.*|)$ $1 [L,NC]  
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a mod_rewrite creating an .htaccess file in your root directory:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ project/$1 [L]
```

Regarding the listing on page, you can easy replace the string as you like:

```
$files = scandir('/path_to_your_project-folder');
foreach($files as $file) {
    echo 'http://sitename.com/' . $file; //clicking on this link the htaccess rule show the right page wrapping the real url
}
```

Hope is helpful for you.